# Javascript dynamically append to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to create a page with a button a textbox and a div.

Whenever I insert a value in the textbox and click the button this value should be inserted in an array and the array will be displayed in the div.

I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> new staff </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = new Array();

function createTable()
{
    var item = document.getElementById('push').value;
    data.push(item);

    var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
    var tbody = '';

    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += 'Cell ' + data[i] + ',' + j;
        tbody += '</td>'
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
<label>Push: <input type="text" name="push" id="push"/></label><br />
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you want to display the value in a table with new row? why you want to store it in array?

Comment: did you check the Javascript console for errors? If you did, you would have discovered your error immediately I think.

Comment: Your code works fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ubfvya5t/

Comment: Will you please make up your mind? Do you have `j` in the code or not? If you do, this is just a typo question and it should be closed. If you don't, there's no problem so the question should be closed. Either way, the question should be closed.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo error... should i delete the post, or it is closed by the moderators?

Answer (score 1):

```
    tbody += 'Cell ' + data[i] + ',' + j;
```

Where are you taking the `j` from? It's not defined anywhere.

Maybe you mean `i`?

Remove it and it will work just fine.

```
tbody += 'Cell ' + data[i] + ',' + i;
```

Comment: Uh oh, he's edited this out of the question.

Comment: Sorry, i cant believe that it was so simple..... Yes this was the answer edit it like the first time in order to anyone with the same question

Comment: My pleasure, and next try to look at the console.. It will save your time..

Answer (score 0):

Try this now: replace "j" with "i" and added a div tag with id as "wrapper".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> new staff </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = new Array();

function createTable()
{
    var item = document.getElementById('push').value;
    data.push(item);

    var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
    var tbody = '';

    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += 'Cell ' + data[i] + ',' + i;
        tbody += '</td>'
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
<label>Push: <input type="text" name="push" id="push"/></label><br />
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He seems to have changed the code in the question, there's no more `j`.

Comment: Ah, I see that. Also his div tag is missing in the body. Thought thats what he was looking for.

Comment: And now there is a div tag in the question too :-)

Comment: sorry, see my previous reply!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the div tag. I checked the edit history and it's been there all along. It's below the form.

Comment: Thats true my bad, copied the text only till </form> tag, missed the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozd3tmch/)

I would recommend getting rid of the nasty onclick method, bad practice. Attach an event listener instead.

Here is the JS.

```
var data = new Array();

function createTable()
{
    var item = document.getElementById('push').value;
    data.push(item);

    var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
    var tbody = '';

    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += data[i];
        tbody += '</td>'
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}

var button = document.querySelector('input[name="generate"]');

button.addEventListener('click', createTable);
```

and the HTML

```
<form name="tablegen">
    <label>Push: <input type="text" name="push" id="push"/></label><br />
    <input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!"/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```